# Receiving exception when attempting to integrate an API using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, server, pusher

Currently, I am working on integrating a chat API (it is called pusher Chatkit) to an app I am working on. For the backend, PHP and laravel are being used, and postman is being used to test the server. When testing on Postman I am receiving a 500 internal server error with this exception:

```html
{
    "message": "You must provide an instance_locator",
    "exception": "Chatkit\\Exceptions\\MissingArgumentException",
    "file": "/Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/pusher/pusher-chatkit-server/src/Chatkit.php",
    "line": 49,
    "trace": [
```

in trace, many files/lines are referred to, so I left out as it is too much to fit in this post (you can ask if needed though and I can make a Gdrive link with it in)

The code leading up to the line + function  being referred to is this:

```html
<?php

namespace Chatkit;

use Chatkit\Exceptions\ChatkitException;
use Chatkit\Exceptions\ConfigurationException;
use Chatkit\Exceptions\ConnectionException;
use Chatkit\Exceptions\MissingArgumentException;
use Chatkit\Exceptions\TypeMismatchException;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class Chatkit
{
    protected $settings = array(
        'scheme'       => 'https',
        'port'         => 80,
        'timeout'      => 30,
        'debug'        => false,
        'curl_options' => array(),
    );
    protected $logger = null;
    protected $ch = null; // Curl handler

    protected $api_settings = array();
    protected $authorizer_settings = array();
    protected $cursor_settings = array();

    const GLOBAL_SCOPE = 'global';
    const ROOM_SCOPE = 'room';

    /**
     *
     * Initializes a new Chatkit instance.
     *
     *
     * @param array $options   Options to configure the Chatkit instance.
     *                         instance_locator - your Chatkit instance locator
     *                         key - your Chatkit instance's key
     *                         scheme - e.g. http or https
     *                         host - the host; no trailing forward slash.
     *                         port - the http port
     *                         timeout - the http timeout
     */
    public function __construct($options)
    {
        $this->checkCompatibility();

        if (!isset($options['instance_locator'])) {
            throw new MissingArgumentException('You must provide an instance_locator');
        }
        if (!isset($options['key'])) {
            throw new MissingArgumentException('You must provide a key');
        }

        $this->settings['instance_locator'] = $options['instance_locator'];
        $this->settings['key'] = $options['key'];
        $this->api_settings['service_name'] = 'chatkit';
        $this->api_settings['service_version'] = 'v2';
        $this->authorizer_settings['service_name'] = 'chatkit_authorizer';
        $this->authorizer_settings['service_version'] = 'v2';
        $this->cursor_settings['service_name'] = 'chatkit_cursors';
        $this->cursor_settings['service_version'] = 'v2';

        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            // only set if valid setting/option
            if (isset($this->settings[$key])) {
                $this->settings[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The instance_locator refers to a code generated on Pusher Chatkit, which I link in my files for integration of that API. This is my first time integrating a backend server using PHP so a little lost! Would appreciate some advice on where I should be looking to solve the issue and also more than happy to provide further info. Cheers

Comment: Wherever you call `$something = new ChatKit($options);`, does that `$options` array contain an entry for `instance_locator`?

Comment: my .env file contains my instance locator, and then I have my config/services.php file which links to that locator, excerpt of code for config/services.php below:

"    'chatkit' => [
    'instanceLocator' => env('CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR'),
    'secret' => env('CHATKIT_SECRET_KEY'),
    ],"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you create API request you should do something like this:

```
$chatkit = new Chatkit(['instance_locator' => *locator*, 'key' => *actualKey*]);
```

The error you are getting means that you haven't passed variables in array.

Comment: You will get the actual values for `instance_locator` and `key` in the Chatkit dashboard - in the tab for Credentials.